# How to create introductory logo when a desktop application starts?

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application

As in Eclipse or Netbeans. When the application starts, a logo is viewed (with a progress bar, loading modules blah blah). I want to know how this popping up of logo can be created with java, more specific with swing component?

Thanks...

Comment: I think netbeans actually includes this in a default GUI project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a feature of Java 6 SE - see:

- http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/splashscreen/
- http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html

Answer (score 3):

Here is a nice Oracle tutorial on [How to Create a Splash Screen](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html)
.

[`SplashScreen`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) is the class you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I got the Term "SplashScreen"